# boot server despite wrong fstab

Tags: ubuntu, boot, linux-kernel, grub2, fstab

I have a kubernetes cluster running on baremetal ubuntu server 16.04 with glusterfs and heketi. Heketi will automatically add volume groups and add those to fstab. Due to $reasons, that volume group might not exist on boot.

If the initramfs encounters a non-existant volume group in the fstab, it will cease to boot and throw the server into grub emergency mode - which really sucks for servers sitting in some data center somewhere in the world.

Is it possible to let the kernel try to continue booting despite a wrong entry in fstab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ubuntu has `systemd`, you can edit `/lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target` and comment out the last two lines:

```
#OnFailure=emergency.target
#OnFailureJobMode=replace-irreversibly
```

I haven't tested this extensively and don't know if there are any risks or side effects involved, but so far it works like a charm. It mounts the root volume and all other volumes, except those that are misconfigured, obviously

Comment: I did not know about those config options, thanks! In the end, the solution was outside the box: I do not use heketi with GlusterFS on the node-level anymore and plan to move from Heketi to a different storage engine altogether. If problems like the one described occur, I cannot really trust the system and it becomes useless for me.